# Drawing Arrows in Tables

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, arrows

What is the best way to draw a diagonal line through the following table?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}}
$e_{1}$ & = & $0$ & $.$ & $d_{1}^{1}$ & $d_{1}^{2}$ & $d_{1}^{3}$ & $d_{1}^{4}$ & $...$ \\
\\
$e_{2}$ & = & $0$ & $.$ & $d_{2}^{1}$ & $d_{2}^{2}$ & $d_{2}^{3}$ & $d_{2}^{4}$ & $...$ \\
\\
$e_{3}$ & = & $0$ & $.$ & $d_{3}^{1}$ & $d_{3}^{2}$ & $d_{3}^{3}$ & $d_{3}^{4}$ & $...$ \\
\\
$e_{4}$ & = & $0$ & $.$ & $d_{4}^{1}$ & $d_{4}^{2}$ & $d_{4}^{3}$ & $d_{4}^{4}$ & $...$ \\
$...$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I want the arrow to hit `$d_{1}^{1}$`, `$d_{2}^{2}$`, etc.

Comment: A tip: If you select the entire code block and hit Ctrl + K (or click the `{}` button above the text field), the code will be marked as such. This also works for inline code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a `TikZ` variant (`\tikzmark` was borrowed from one of Andrew Stacey's answers):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{array}{*{9}{c}}
    e_{1} & = & 0 & . & \tikzmark{a}d_{1}^{1} & d_{1}^{2} & d_{1}^{3} & d_{1}^{4} & ... \\
    \\
    e_{2} & = & 0 & . & d_{2}^{1} & d_{2}^{2} & d_{2}^{3} & d_{2}^{4} & ... \\
    \\
    e_{3} & = & 0 & . & d_{3}^{1} & d_{3}^{2} & d_{3}^{3} & d_{3}^{4} & ... \\
    \\
    e_{4} & = & 0 & . & d_{4}^{1} & d_{4}^{2} & d_{4}^{3} & d_{4}^{4}\tikzmark{b} & ... \\
    ... \\
    \end{array}
\]
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[-triangle 45] ($(a.north east)+(-0.2,0.2)$) -- ($(b.south west)+(0.3,-0.2)$);

\end{document}
```

[image]

For other different predefined arrow tips, refer to Section **23 Arrow Tip Library** of the `pgf` manual.

Comment: Is there any way to increase the size of the arrowhead in this solution?

Comment: Also, is there any way to fix the result so that `$d_{1}^{1}$` and `$d_{4}^{4}$` are not oddly lowered beneath the other symbols?

Comment: @jamaicanworm:please see my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  How can I add an axis variable name, as in $x$, at the end of the arrow? (my arrow is horizontal or vertical, and no text  rotation is needed)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`pst-node`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node) and a `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf` (or `xelatex`) compile sequence to produce the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{array}{*{9}{c}}
    e_{1} & = & 0 & . & \rnode{A}{d_{1}^{1}} & d_{1}^{2} & d_{1}^{3} & d_{1}^{4} & ... \\
    \\
    e_{2} & = & 0 & . & d_{2}^{1} & d_{2}^{2} & d_{2}^{3} & d_{2}^{4} & ... \\
    \\
    e_{3} & = & 0 & . & d_{3}^{1} & d_{3}^{2} & d_{3}^{3} & d_{3}^{4} & ... \\
    \\
    e_{4} & = & 0 & . & d_{4}^{1} & d_{4}^{2} & d_{4}^{3} & \rnode{B}{d_{4}^{4}} & ... \\
    ... \\
    \end{array}
\]
\ncline[nodesep=-1.2\baselineskip,linewidth=.4pt]{->}{A}{B}% Draw line
\end{document}
```

`\rnode{<node>}{<stuff>}` makes one able to reference `<stuff>` via `<node>`. `\ncline` is used to draw the `n`ode `c`onnection lines between the specified nodes. Since this draws on the rich [`pstricks`](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) library, you can modify the colour, width, presentation and style of the line as needed.

Note that I've changed your "entirely mathematical `tabular`" to an `array` environment, which is its intended use. Additionally, instead of centering it (via the `center` environment), I've place the entire `array` in a display math environment (using `\[` and `\]`).

---

More pronounced arrow definitions is possible via some of the basic `pstricks` arrow head modifications. One could use the options (key-value) `arrowsize=<dim> <num>`, `arrowlength=<dim>`, `arrowinset=<num>` or `arrowscale=<factor>`. Here is some detail from the [`pstricks` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf) (p 28, section **15 Arrowheads and such**):

[image]

For example, try

```
\ncline[nodesep=-1.2\baselineskip,linewidth=.4pt,arrowsize=3pt 2]{->}{A}{B}% Draw line
```

Comment: Thanks!  How can I fix the arrow so that the arrowhead is more pronounced?

Comment: @jamaicanworm: I've added some detail to modify that. Try my last suggestion.

Comment: @jamaicanworm: use `arrowscale=2`

Comment: Thanks!  I think the TikZ variant is easier for my setup, but I would like to know how to get the arrow bigger for that one as well.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ to draw the arrow (by using the nodes created by `nicematrix` in the array).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{NiceMatrix}
  e_{1} & = & 0 & . & d_{1}^{1} & d_{1}^{2} & d_{1}^{3} & d_{1}^{4} & ... \\
\\
  e_{2} & = & 0 & . & d_{2}^{1} & d_{2}^{2} & d_{2}^{3} & d_{2}^{4} & ... \\
\\
  e_{3} & = & 0 & . & d_{3}^{1} & d_{3}^{2} & d_{3}^{3} & d_{3}^{4} & ... \\
\\
  e_{4} & = & 0 & . & d_{4}^{1} & d_{4}^{2} & d_{4}^{3} & d_{4}^{4}& ... \\
... \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [shorten > = -2mm , ->] (1-5.north west) -- (7-8.south east) ;
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]