# How write a symbol of the circle in the Latex?

Tags: symbols, diagrams

[image]

How write a symbol of the circle in the Latex?

Comment: There was also a question about a matrix with diagonal lines like that (although in the opposite direction), but I can't find it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what it is you want? Drawing a circle is easy, but it's not as complicated as putting text in that circle – and that's saying quite a thing, because the latter is easy, too. :-)

Comment: @Alenanno It was about diagonal arrows (easy change) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38169/drawing-multiple-diagonal-arrows-in-a-table

Comment: @R.Schumacher Oh that's another one but the one I was referring to was with a Tikz Matrix (done with a foreach) and it had couples like (0,0), (1,1), and so on. :D