# Matrix with inclined lines?

Tags: matrices, addlines

I would like to know how to add inclined lines in Matrix [image]

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257043/how-can-i-highlight-elements-in-a-matrix

Comment: Please, don't teach Sarrus’ rule.

Comment: Please observe, that the vertical line should be after the third column, if you are trying to illustrate some variant of Sarrus' scheme.

Comment: @egreg +1. I always fight against using it instead of using properties of determinats.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Yes: students immediately generalize it to higher order matrices. `;-)`