# Adding nested backgrounds to a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, nodes, plot

I am trying to recreate the following diagram with TikZ.

[image]

Here is what I have

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick},squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick}]
\node[squarednode] (theta_I) {$\theta_e^I$};
\node[squarednode] (theta_V) [right=10mm of theta_I] {$\theta_e^V$};
\node[squarednode] (theta_Y) [right=10mm of theta_V] {$\theta_e^Y$};
\node[roundnode] (I_ne) [below=10mm of theta_I] {$I_{ne}$};
\node[roundnode] (V_ne) [below=10mm of theta_V] {$V_{ne}$};
\node[roundnode] (Y_ne) [below=10mm of theta_Y] {$Y_{ne}$};
\node[roundnode] (X_ne) [below=10mm of V_ne] {$X_{ne}$};
\node[squarednode] (theta_X) [below=10mm of X_ne] {$\theta^X$};

\draw[->, ultra thick] (theta_I.south) -- (I_ne.north);
\draw[->, ultra thick] (theta_V.south) -- (V_ne.north);
\draw[->, ultra thick] (theta_Y.south) -- (Y_ne.north);
\draw[->, ultra thick] (I_ne.south) -- (X_ne.north west);
\draw[->, ultra thick] (V_ne.south) -- (X_ne.north);
\draw[->, ultra thick] (Y_ne.south) -- (X_ne.north east);
\draw[->, ultra thick] (Y_ne.west) -- (V_ne.east);
\draw[->, ultra thick] (X_ne.south) -- (theta_X.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How do I add the backgrounds to it? Preferably I want a shaded background, say light blue for the outer "E" background and dark blue for the inner "N" background.

Comment: PLease extend your code snippet to complete small document  (Minimal Working Example: MWE). Use of `forest` package and `fit` Ti*k*Z library seems to be promising way to solve your problem.

Comment: @Zarko Done. The `fit` library seems promising, but I'm not sure about `forest`. This is not exactly a tree if you look closely: there is an additional edge from `Y_{ne}` to `V_{ne}`.

Comment: Thank you for edit. This can be done by growing tri above, I will show thi (if someone else will do this before, ASAP I will have some spare time ...

Comment: Looks more like a `\matrix` to me than a tree but both are possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tikzcd` and a `forest` solution that share the styles `vert down`, `lab` and `lab'`. Both use `fit` to draw a rectangular around a set of nodes as part of the `submatrix` key.

I've connected `\theta^X` to `X_{ne}` and not any of the rectangle since the arrow in your sketch doesn't touch any rectangle's border.

I have defined the `\bgarrow` macro for `tikzcd` in a [previous answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664328/16595).

Both solutions create a “fake” `inner` node that exists only for the `outer` node for reference. After the `outer` node has created (and has been placed on the `background`) the `inner` node will be placed on top of the `outer` one but still on the `background`.

If you have to use this with more than two rectangulars, an easier solution will need to be developed (say a list of rectangles that will be *faked* from top to bottom but drawn from bottom to top).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, forest}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds}
\makeatletter
\let\tikzcd@ar@new@orig\tikzcd@ar@new
\def\tikzcd@ar@new@bg[#1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664328/16595
  \pgfutil@g@addto@macro\tikzcd@savedpaths{%
    \pgfonlayer{background}\path[/tikz/commutative diagrams/.cd,every arrow,#1]%
    (\tikzcd@ar@start\tikzcd@startanchor)to(\tikzcd@ar@target\tikzcd@endanchor);
    \endpgfonlayer}\let\tikzcd@ar@new\tikzcd@ar@new@orig}
\tikzcdset{every diagram/.append code=%
  \def\bgarrow{\let\tikzcd@ar@new\tikzcd@ar@new@bg\tikzcd@arrow}%
  \let\bgar\bgarrow}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  vert down/.style={to path={--(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget.north)\tikztonodes}},
  lab/.style={label={[anchor=south east]south east:$#1$}},
  lab'/.style={label={[anchor=south west,name=placeholder,xshift=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}]
    south east:\phantom{$#1$}}},
  submatrix/.style args={[#1]#2:#3}{
    fit={#2},name={#3},node contents=,draw,#1}}
\tikzset{
  roundnode/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick},
  squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick}}

%% tikzcd
\tikzcdset{
  submatrix/.style args={[#1]#2:#3}{
    to path={node[inner sep=+.85ex,name prefix=\tikzcdmatrixname-,submatrix={[{#1}]{#2}:{#3}}]}},
  rows'/.style 2 args={
    /utils/temp/.style={/tikz/row ##1/.append style={nodes={#2}}},/utils/temp/.list={#1}}}

%% forest
\tikzset{forest edge/.style={style/.expanded=\forestoption{edge}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  column sep=small, rows'={1,4}{squarednode}, rows'={2,3}{roundnode}]
\theta_e^I & \theta_e^V & \theta_e^Y \\
   F_{ne} \drar
 & V_{ne} \dar
 & Y_{ne} \dlar \lar \\
 & X_{ne} \\
 & \theta^X \uar
%
\arrow  [submatrix={[path only,    lab'=E               ](2-1)(2-3)(3-2)          :inner}]
\bgarrow[submatrix={[fill=blue!10, lab=E                ](1-2)(inner)(placeholder):outer}]
\bgarrow[submatrix={[fill=blue!40, lab=N, inner sep=+0pt](inner)                  :inner}]
%
\arrow[from=1-1, to=inner, vert down]
\arrow[from=1-2, to=inner, vert down]
\arrow[from=1-3, to=inner, vert down]
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow'=90, math content, edge+=<-},
  where level={0}{squarednode}{}, where level={3}{squarednode}{},
  where level={1}{roundnode}{},   where level={2}{roundnode}{},
[\theta^X
  [X_{ne}, edge+=->
    [F_{ne} [\theta_e^I, no edge]]
    [V_{ne} [\theta_e^V, no edge]]
    [Y_{ne} [\theta_e^Y, no edge]]
  ]
]
%
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node[submatrix={[path only, lab'=E]  (!1)(!11)(!12)(!13)                   :inner}];
    \node[submatrix={[fill=blue!10, lab=E](inner)(!111)(!121)(!131)(placeholder):outer}];
    \node[submatrix={[fill=blue!40, lab=N, inner sep=+0pt](inner)               :inner}];
\end{pgfonlayer}
\foreach \thet in {1,2,3}
  \path[forest edge,->] (!1\thet 1) edge[vert down] (inner);
\path[forest edge] (!12) edge (!13);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dang, those pictures are always so big …