# How can I add clusters over grid nodes in this figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tkz-graph

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\SetGraphUnit{2}



\Vertex[x=0,y=0]{1}
\Vertex[x=2,y=0]{2}
\Vertex[x=2,y=2]{3}
\Vertex[x=0,y=2]{4}
%%
\Edge(1)(2)
\Edge(2)(3)
\Edge(3)(4)
\Edge(4)(1)
%%
\Vertex[x=2,y=4]{5}
\Vertex[x=4,y=4]{6}
\Vertex[x=4,y=6]{7}
\Vertex[x=2,y=6]{8}
%%
\Edge(4)(5)
\Edge(5)(6)
\Edge(6)(7)
\Edge(7)(8)
\Edge(8)(5)
%%
\Vertex[x=4,y=0]{9}
\Vertex[x=6,y=0]{10}
\Vertex[x=6,y=2]{11}
\Vertex[x=4,y=2]{12}
%%
\Edge(9)(10)
\Edge(10)(11)
\Edge(11)(12)
\Edge(12)(9)
\Edge(11)(6)
%%



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

This should generate:

[image]

> Question: How can I add colored cluster over each of the three 4-node cliques. I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Over with opacity? The blue ones are easy with the [`fit` library](https://tikz.dev/library-fit). The red one maybe, too.

Comment: Thank you very much, based on your suggestion drawing the clusters went pretty smooth, but I still have to draw them with opacity @Qrrbrbirlbel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With plain TikZ and the library `fit` this can be done. I've added the `backgrounds` library and placed those boxes behind the edges and vertices. I've also chosen only a `fill opacity` (and no `draw opacity`) which means the borders are still fully opaque. There's also an all-encompassing [`opacity`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transparency#sec-23.2) key.

The [`rotate fit` key](https://tikz.dev/library-fit#tikz/rotate:fit) is essential for the red boxes.

Since the `fit` library only checks the north, east, south and west anchors when determining the size we have to explicitly give a list of four coordinates.

---

In this simple case, I've also explictily given the rotation angles. If you need this automatically, a bit more work is necessary.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  fitty/.style={
    fill opacity=.7,
    draw=#1!80,
    fill=#1!50,
    rounded corners,
  }
]
\SetGraphUnit{2}

\Vertex[x=0,y=0]{1}   \Vertex[x=2,y=0]{2}
\Vertex[x=2,y=2]{3}   \Vertex[x=0,y=2]{4}
%%
\Edge(1)(2)   \Edge(2)(3)
\Edge(3)(4)   \Edge(4)(1)
%%
\Vertex[x=2,y=4]{5}  \Vertex[x=4,y=4]{6}
\Vertex[x=4,y=6]{7}  \Vertex[x=2,y=6]{8}
%%
\Edge(4)(5)   \Edge(5)(6)
\Edge(6)(7)   \Edge(7)(8)
\Edge(8)(5)
%%
\Vertex[x=4,y=0]{9}  \Vertex[x=6,y=0]{10}
\Vertex[x=6,y=2]{11} \Vertex[x=4,y=2]{12}
%%
\Edge(9)(10)  \Edge(10)(11)
\Edge(11)(12) \Edge(12)(9)
\Edge(11)(6)
%%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\foreach \corners in {(8)(6), (1)(3), (9)(11)}
  \node[fitty=blue, fit=\corners]{};

\foreach \rot/\corners in {
  45/(4.south west) (5.north east)(4.north west) (5.south east),
 -45/(6.north west)(11.south east)(6.north east)(11.south west)}
\node[rotate fit=\rot, fit=\corners, fitty=red]{};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `\bgarrow` we can almost do the same [with `tikzcd`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/665917)