# Tikz arrows covering text

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-matrix

The images linked below show what I want to do and what I get. I'm completely new to Tikz. What am I doing wrong?

```
       \text{det}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
                a_{11}\tikzmark{a11} & a_{12}\tikzmark{a12} & a_{13}\tikzmark{a13} \\
                a_{21} & a_{22}\tikzmark{a22} & a_{23}\tikzmark{a23} \\
                a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\tikzmark{a33} \\
       \end{array}\right]
       \begin{array}{cc}
                a_{11} & a_{12} \\
                a_{21}\tikzmark{a21} & a_{22} \\
                a_{31}\tikzmark{a31} & a_{32}\tikzmark{a31} \\
       \end{array} =(a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}+a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}+a_{13}a_{21}a_{32}) - (a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}+a_{11}a_{23}a_{32}+a_{12}a_{21}a_{33}).
       \end{equation}

       \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
            \draw [-] ({pic cs:a11}) to ({pic cs:a22});
            \draw [-] ({pic cs:a22}) to ({pic cs:a33});
            \draw [-] ({pic cs:a12}) to ({pic cs:a23});
       \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257043/how-can-i-highlight-elements-in-a-matrix. Maybe you'll like it :-)

Comment: @Mensch sure, could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Start the minimal working example, short MWE, with `\documentclass` and end it with `\end{document}`. Make it as short as possiblie resulting in your issue ... Then we can copy your MWE and test it on our own coputers to find the error ...

Comment: @Serpent Did you find any help with your question? If so, would you mind upvoting and accepting one of those?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with `pstricks`, using `blkarray`: each element is defined as an `\Rnode`. Next each relevant pair of nodes are connected with a node connection:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

    \[ \begin{blockarray}{r@{\enspace}[ccc]cc}
        & \Rnode{A11}{a_{11}} & \Rnode{A12}{a_{12}} & \Rnode{A13}{a_{13}} & \Rnode{B11}{a_{11}} & \Rnode{B12}{a_{12}}\\
       \det{} & a_{21} & \Rnode{A22}{a_{22}} & \Rnode{A23}{a_{23}} & \Rnode{A21}{a_{21}} & a_{22}\\
         & \Rnode{B31}{a_{31}} & \Rnode{B32}{a_{32}} & \Rnode{A33}{a_{33}} \bigstrut[b] & \Rnode{A31}{a_{31}} & \Rnode{A32}{a_{32}}
        \end{blockarray} \]
        \psset{nodesep=0.5pt, linewidth=0.5pt, arrowinset=0.2, linejoin=1}
     \foreach \s \t in{A11/A22, A22/A33, A12/A23, A23/A31, A13/A21, A21/A32}%
     {\ncline[linecolor=Lavender]{->}{\s}{\t}}
     \foreach \s \t in{B31/A22, A22/A13, B32/A23, A23/B11, A33/A21, A21/B12}%
     {\ncline[linecolor=Moccasin]{->}{\s}{\t}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, where is \det in your code? It is a bit below in the image.

Comment: @Sebastiano: `bloackarray` has some problems  with centring w.r.t. the maths axis. Checking,  I see that I had a copy-paste accident. I'll fix  all that in a moment. Thank  you for pointing it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `Nicematrix` that I find pretty elegant:
[image: det with nicematrix]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    arp/.style={cyan,line width=1pt,opacity=0.5,->},
    arm/.style={orange,line width=1pt,opacity=0.5,->}}

\begin{document}
    
    \def\r{.5} % ratio for arrows outer length
    
    \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=5pt}
    $\det%
    \begin{NiceArray}{[*{3}{W{c}{15pt}}]*{2}{W{c}{15pt}}}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{11} & a_{12}\\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{21} & a_{22}\\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{31} & a_{32}\\
        
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz 
        \foreach \i [count=\j from 3] in {1,2,3} \draw[arp] ($(1-\i)!-\r!(3-\j)$) -- ($(3-\j)!-\r!(1-\i)$) node[pos=1.1] {\Large $\oplus$};
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz 
        \foreach \i [count=\j from 3] in {1,2,3} \draw[arm] ($(1-\j)!-\r!(3-\i)$) -- ($(3-\i)!-\r!(1-\j)$) node[pos=1.1] {\Large $\ominus$};
    \end{NiceArray}%
    \quad=\quad\dots$\\ 
    
\end{document}
```