# TikZ-matrix: add brackets around some blocks inside

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

How can I get brackets (say *"normal parenthese math brackets"*) inside a TikZ-matrix around some blocks?
For example here at the marked places:

[image]

Is there a *decoration* or something?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,
row sep=5mm, column sep=3mm,
]{
a11 & a12 & a13 & a14 & a15 \\
a21 & a22 & a23 & a24 & a25 \\
a31 & a32 & a33 & a34 & a35 \\
a41 & a42 & a43 & a44 & a45 \\
a51 & a52 & a53 & a54 & a55 \\
a61 & a62 & a63 & a64 & a65 \\
a71 & a72 & a73 & a74 & a75 \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

For information, here is what you can do with `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`. That package uses PGF (which is a sublayer of Tikz) but does not load Tikz and does not use the library `matrix` of Tikz.

However, each cell is a PGF node that the user can use with standard Tiks instructions.

There is a command `\SubMatrix` to add brackets. The brackets are the standard brackets of the mathematical expressions of LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
$\begin{NiceMatrix}
a11 & a12 & a13 & a14 & a15 \\
a21 & a22 & a23 & a24 & a25 \\
a31 & a32 & a33 & a34 & a35 \\
a41 & a42 & a43 & a44 & a45 \\
a51 & a52 & a53 & a54 & a55 \\
a61 & a62 & a63 & a64 & a65 \\
a71 & a72 & a73 & a74 & a75 \\
\CodeAfter [delimiters/color=blue]
  \SubMatrix({1-4}{2-5})
  \SubMatrix({5-1}{7-3})
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because of the PGF nodes.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Parenthesis you can dear :-)

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, % <-- added matrix name
             row sep=3mm, 
             column sep=3mm,
            ]
{
a11 & a12 & a13 & a14 & a15 \\
a21 & a22 & a23 & a24 & a25 \\
a31 & a32 & a33 & a34 & a35 \\
a41 & a42 & a43 & a44 & a45 \\
a51 & a52 & a53 & a54 & a55 \\
a61 & a62 & a63 & a64 & a65 \\
a71 & a72 & a73 & a74 & a75 \\
};
\draw[thick, blue, rounded corners=2mm]
    ([xshift=+2mm] m-1-4.north west) -| (m-2-4.south west) -- ++ (+2mm,0)
    ([xshift=-2mm] m-1-5.north east) -| (m-2-5.south east) -- ++ (-2mm,0)
%
    ([xshift=+2mm] m-5-1.north west) -| (m-7-1.south west) -- ++ (+2mm,0)
    ([xshift=-2mm] m-5-3.north east) -| (m-7-3.south east) -- ++ (-2mm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get original amsmath-brackets, I worked with some tricks due to length-measurement of the calc-library:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/savevalue/.code 2 args={\global\edef#1{#2}}}
%\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\InnerSep}{1pt} % optional 1/2

\begin{document}

\section{amsmath-Brackets inside a TikZ-matrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
row sep=5mm, column sep=3mm,
nodes={draw=none, % Test
%inner sep=\InnerSep % optional 2/2
},
% Maybe useful:
%every odd row/.style={anchor=base west},% <--- don't know, how
%every even row/.style={anchor=base west},% to make this shorter
](m){
a11 a2& a12 & a13 & a14 & a15 \\
a21 & a22 & a23 & a24 & a25 \\
a31 & a32 & a33 & a34 & a35 \\
a41 & a42 & a43 & a44 & a45 \\
a51 & a52 & a53 & a54 & a55 \\
a61 & a62 & a63 & a64 & a65 \\
a71 & a72 & a73 & a74 & a75 \\
};

% Brackets around A
\coordinate[](Aul) at (m-5-1.north west);
\coordinate[](All) at (m-7-1.south west);
\coordinate[](Aur) at (m-5-3.north east);
\coordinate[](Alr) at (m-7-3.south east);

\path let \p1=($(Aul)-(All)$) in 
\pgfextra{  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}   }
[savevalue={\u}{\templength}];
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\uHalf}{0.5*\u}

\node[] at ($(Aul)!0.5!(All)$) {$
\left( \rule[-\uHalf]{0mm}{\u}  \right.$};

\node[] at ($(Aur)!0.5!(Alr)$) {$
\left. \rule[-\uHalf]{0mm}{\u} \right)$};

% Brackets around B
\coordinate[](Bul) at (m-1-4.north west);
\coordinate[](Bll) at (m-2-4.south west);
\coordinate[](Bur) at (m-1-5.north east);
\coordinate[](Blr) at (m-2-5.south east);

\path let \p1=($(Bul)-(Bll)$) in 
\pgfextra{  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}   }
[savevalue={\u}{\templength}];
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\uHalf}{0.5*\u*1}

\node[blue] at ($(Bul)!0.5!(Bll)$) {$
\left( \rule[-\uHalf]{0mm}{\u}  \right.$};

\node[blue] at ($(Bur)!0.5!(Blr)$) {$
\left. \rule[-\uHalf]{0mm}{\u} \right)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{For Comparison: Brackets at amsmath-Matrix}
$\begin{pmatrix}
a51 & a52 & a53 \\[5mm]
a61 & a62 & a63  \\[5mm]
a71 & a72 & a73
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `matrix` library of TikZ already comes with a tool to put delimiters around a `\matrix`. We can re-use that to put delimiteres around any nodes.

---

My *first* approach was to define a new macro

```
\newcommand*\delimAroundTikZCells[5][]{%
  \path[every delim around tikz cells/.try,#1,local bounding box=datc]
    (#2.north west)(#3.south east) [freeze local bounding box=datc]
    (datc) [late options={left delimiter=#4, right delimiter=#5}];}
```

that can be used as such (when the matrix is named `a`):

```
\delimAroundTikZCells{a-1-4}{a-2-5}()
\delimAroundTikZCells{a-5-1}{a-7-3}()
```

This commands puts a rectangular node around the range provided by `#2` and `#3` (this is similar to the `fit` key from the `fit` library) and then adds to delimiters `#4` (left) and `#5` (right) around this new pseudo-node.

---

Though, we can do this also as an option to the matrix it self with my *second* solution, the keys are

- `lr delim = <left><left options> and <right><right options> around <top left> to <bottom left>`  and similarly
- `ab delim`.

The options are optionally. This also works without explicitly naming the matrix.

There are a lot of `{` and `}` involved because the `\tikzlastnode` macro gets overwritten by the way the `late options` work.

---

Since the nodes have some `inner xsep`s (default `.3333em`) I've added a `delim xshift` and `delim yshift` key that can be used to correct the placement of delimiters.

Due to how these delimiters are set these options (as all styles like `every [left|right|above|below] delimiter`) need to be defined at an encompassing group, that could be the `tikzpicture` it self, a `scope`, `\scoped` (though this needs `ampersand replacemnt`) or simply

```
\path[delim xshift = .5em, lr delims = green] node[
  matrix of nodes,
  lr delim = ( and ) around 2-2 to 4-4] {
  <matrix content>
};
```

I've added a key `delim options` as a way to set options that apply to all delimiters that come after it and are added with the keys `lr delim` and `ab delim`.

---

Internally, the delimiters are real math delimiters done via

```
\left( <a box with the same height as the node> \right.
```

I've also added a more `tabular`/`array` like version of the TikZ `\matrix` for comparison.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
  delim options/.style={append after command={[#1]}},
  lr delims/.style={
    every delim around tikz cells/.append style={
      every left delimiter/.append style={#1},
      every right delimiter/.append style={#1}}},
  ab delims/.style={
    every delim around tikz cells/.append style={
      every above delimiter/.append style={#1},
      every below delimiter/.append style={#1}}},
  delim xshift/.style={
    every delim around tikz cells/.append style={
      every left delimiter/.append style={xshift={#1}},
      every right delimiter/.append style={xshift={-(#1)}}}},
  delim yshift/.style={
    every delim around tikz cells/.append style={
      every above delimiter/.append style={yshift={-(#1)}},
      every below delimiter/.append style={yshift={#1}}}},
  lr delim/.style args={#1#2 and #3#4 around #5 to #6}{% Left Right
    append after command={
      {{[local bounding box=@] (\tikzlastnode-#5.north west)(\tikzlastnode-#6.south east)}
      (@)[every delim around tikz cells/.try,
          every left delimiter/.append style={#2},
          every right delimiter/.append style={#4},
          late options={left delimiter={#1},right delimiter={#3}}]}[]}},
  ab delim/.style args={#1#2 and #3#4 around #5 to #6}{% Above Below
    append after command={
      {{[local bounding box=@] (\tikzlastnode-#5.north west)(\tikzlastnode-#6.south east)}
      (@)[every delim around tikz cells/.try,
          every above delimiter/.append style={#2},
          every below delimiter/.append style={#4},
          late options={above delimiter={#1},below delimiter={#3}}]}[]}},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  delim yshift=.8ex,
  delim xshift=.5em,
  lr delims=blue]
\matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=5mm,
  column sep=3mm,
  lr delim=( and ) around 1-4 to 2-5,
  lr delim=( and ) around 5-1 to 7-3,
  ab delim={[ red and ] green around 1-2 to 4-3},
] (a) { a11 & a12 & a13 & a14 & a15 \\ a21 & a22 & a23 & a24 & a25 \\
        a31 & a32 & a33 & a34 & a35 \\ a41 & a42 & a43 & a44 & a45 \\
        a51 & a52 & a53 & a54 & a55 \\ a61 & a62 & a63 & a64 & a65 \\
        a71 & a72 & a73 & a74 & a75 \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=0mm, column sep=2\tabcolsep,
  inner sep=0pt, execute at begin node=\strut,
  delim options={delim xshift=.1em, lr delims=blue},
  lr delim=( and ) around 1-4 to 2-5,
  lr delim=( and ) around 5-1 to 7-3] (a) {
  a11 & a12 & a13 & a14 & a15 \\ a21 & a22 & a23 & a24 & a25 \\
  a31 & a32 & a33 & a34 & a35 \\ a41 & a42 & a43 & a44 & a45 \\
  a51 & a52 & a53 & a54 & a55 \\ a61 & a62 & a63 & a64 & a65 \\
  a71 & a72 & a73 & a74 & a75 \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Nice and very useful solution! +1!

Comment: Sorry for late response. Unfortunately your edited MWE doesn't work. It gives me error `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/appendafter command', to 
which you passed '[delim xshift=.1em, lr delims=blue]', and I am going to ignor
e it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` I tested with recent MiKTeX.

Comment: @Zarko Whoops. Yes, that was a typo in the fifth line.

Comment: Now works! Thank you very much.