# Curly braces around the tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I am planning to draw the following pictures like this:

[image]

So far I have tried this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,graphics,graphicx,supertabular}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,positioning,calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m)
  {
    \node {\textbf{Name}}; & \node{\textbf{Age}}; & \node {\textbf{Balance}}; \\ \hline
    \node {User 1}; & \node{35}; & \node {7}; \\
    \node {User 2}; & \node{42}; & \node {7}; \\
    \node { }; & \node{ }; & \node { }; \\
    \node {User 3}; & \node{42}; & \node {7}; \\
    \node {User 4}; & \node{42}; & \node {7}; \\
  };
  \draw[decorate] (m-2-2.north east) -- node[right=2pt] {$m$} (m-2-4.south east); % right
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve this desired output? Not exactly the arrow should be like. They should be clean and nicer arrows.

Also I need this to draw:

[image]

Comment: For this kind of output, [nicematrix](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix) can be helpful.

Comment: @projetmbc I see :), but some of my code have already drawn using matrix.

Comment: Related: [Q630692](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660470)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```latex
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow,graphics,graphicx,supertabular}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m1) [matrix of nodes]
          {
            \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Age} & \textbf{Balance} \\ \hline
            User 1 & 35 & 7 \\
            User 2 & 42 & 7 \\
            &    &   \\
            User 3 & 42 & 7 \\
            User 4 & 42 & 7 \\
          };

  \matrix [right=of m1] (m2) [matrix of nodes]
          {
            \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Age} \\ \hline
            User 1 & 35 \\
            User 2 & 42 \\
                   &    \\
            User 3 & 42 \\
            User 4 & 42 \\
          };

  \draw[decorate,
    decoration={
      brace,
      mirror,
      amplitude=5pt,
      raise = 1pt,
    },
    thick,
  ] (m1-2-1.west) -- (m1-6-1.west)
  node [
    pos=0.5,
    left=5pt,
  ] { text };

  \draw[decorate,
    decoration={
      brace,
      mirror,
      amplitude=5pt,
      raise = 1pt,
    },
    thick,
  ] (m1-6-1.south west) -- (m1-6-3.south east)
  node [
    pos=0.5,
    below=5pt,
  ] { text };

  \draw[decorate,
    decoration={
      brace,
      mirror,
      amplitude=5pt,
      raise = 1pt,
    },
    thick,
  ] (m2-6-1.south west) -- (m2-6-2.south east)
  node [
    pos=0.5,
    below=5pt,
  ] { text };

  \draw[decorate,
    decoration={
      brace,
      amplitude=5pt,
      raise = 1pt,
    },
    ultra thick,
  ] (m1-1-1.north west) -- (m2-1-2.north east)
  node [
    pos=0.5,
    above=5pt,
  ] { text };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample]

Comment: This is a nicer solution. +1

Answer (score 4):

Also with `matrix` library, but with `calligraphy` braces and all picture elements style definition as `tikzpicture` options:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                    calligraphy,
                matrix,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 7mm,
BC/.style args = {#1/#2}{decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1mm,
        post=moveto, post length=1mm,
        raise=#1},% for mirroring of brace
        very thick,
        pen colour=#2},
 M/.style = {matrix of nodes,
             nodes={minimum width=4em, minimum height=3ex},
             row sep=0ex,
             row 1/.append style = {nodes={font=\bfseries}},
            },
 N/.style = {font=\small, sloped}
                        ]
\matrix (m1) [M]
{
Name    &   Age &   Balance \\ 
    \hline
User 1  & 35 & 7 \\
User 2  & 42 & 7 \\
User 3  & 42 & 7 \\
User 4  & 42 & 7 \\
};
\matrix[right=of m1] (m2) [M]
{
Name    &   Age \\ 
    \hline
User 1  & 35 \\
User 2  & 42 \\
User 3  & 42 \\
User 4  & 42 \\
};

\draw[BC=1mm/red]   (m1.north west) -- node[above=3mm] {text above}  (m2.north east);
\draw[BC=1mm/red]   (m1-5-1.south west) -- node[left =3mm] {text left}  (m1-2-1.north west);
\draw[BC=1mm/red]   (m1.south east) -- node[below=3mm] {text below}  (m1.south west);
\draw[BC=1mm/red]   (m2.south east) -- node[below=3mm] {text below}  (m2.south west);
%
\draw[BC=1mm/red]   (m2-2-2.north east) -- node[right=3mm] {text right}  (m2-3-2.south east);
\draw[BC=1mm/red]   (m2-4-2.north east) -- node[right=3mm] {text right}  (m2-5-2.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]