# Use tikz or anything else to draw the demonstration figure for the 3rd-order matrix determinant

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-matrix

I try to draw the following picture by using TikZ and `\tikzmarknode`.
[image]

The straight line segments are easy to draw, but how to draw the curve parts?

My code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{vmatrix}
  \tikzmarknode{11}{a_{11}} & \tikzmarknode{12}{a_{12}} & \tikzmarknode{13}{a_{13}} \\
  \tikzmarknode{21}{a_{21}} & \tikzmarknode{22}{a_{22}} & \tikzmarknode{23}{a_{23}} \\
  \tikzmarknode{31}{a_{31}} & \tikzmarknode{32}{a_{32}} & \tikzmarknode{33}{a_{33}}
\end{vmatrix}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw (11)--(22)--(33);
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw (12)--(23);
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw (21)--(32);
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw[densely dashed] (31)--(22)--(13);
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw[densely dashed] (21)--(12);
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw[densely dashed] (32)--(23);\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As example for similar problem see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257043/how-can-i-highlight-elements-in-a-matrix. You may liked it ...

Comment: A matrix of math nodes (https://mirror.clientvps.com/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf, page 711, section 59.1) may be the right tool, like in the example to which Zarko referred to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something link this (the values are approximations found via trial and error) maybe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{vmatrix}
  \tikzmarknode{11}{a_{11}} & \tikzmarknode{12}{a_{12}} & \tikzmarknode{13}{a_{13}} \\
  \tikzmarknode{21}{a_{21}} & \tikzmarknode{22}{a_{22}} & \tikzmarknode{23}{a_{23}} \\
  \tikzmarknode{31}{a_{31}} & \tikzmarknode{32}{a_{32}} & \tikzmarknode{33}{a_{33}}
\end{vmatrix}\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw (11)--(22)--(33);
    \draw (12)--(23);
    \draw (21)--(32);
    \draw[densely dashed] (31)--(22)--(13);
    \draw[densely dashed] (21)--(12);
    \draw[densely dashed] (32)--(23);

    \draw[rounded corners] (31)--++(1.25,-0.65)--++(1.25,0.65)--(23);
    \draw[rounded corners] (32)--++(1.25,-0.65)--++(1.25,0.65)--(13);
    \draw[rounded corners, densely dashed] (11)--++(1.25,0.65)--++(1.25,-0.65)--(23);
    \draw[rounded corners, densely dashed] (12)--++(1.25,0.65)--++(1.25,-0.65)--(33);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that due to the use of `overlay`, the lines may overlay the text before and after the matrix. So, you may want to add some additional spacing.

---

Another way would be to use a `vNiceMatrix` provided by the `nicematrix` package. You can then directly reference to the matrix nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{vNiceMatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (1-1)--(2-2)--(3-3);
        \draw (1-2)--(2-3);
        \draw (2-1)--(3-2);
        \draw[densely dashed] (3-1)--(2-2)--(1-3);
        \draw[densely dashed] (2-1)--(1-2);
        \draw[densely dashed] (3-2)--(2-3);
        
        \draw[rounded corners] (3-1)--++(1.25,-0.65)--++(1.25,0.65)--(2-3);
        \draw[rounded corners] (3-2)--++(1.25,-0.65)--++(1.25,0.65)--(1-3);
        \draw[rounded corners, densely dashed] (1-1)--++(1.25,0.65)--++(1.25,-0.65)--(2-3);
        \draw[rounded corners, densely dashed] (1-2)--++(1.25,0.65)--++(1.25,-0.65)--(3-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{vNiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried using this with text above or below the matrix? The `overlay` will lead to the lines not to be considered by TeX when determining the space above or below the matrix.

Comment: You are right. Some additional spacing would be needed to avoid this. Do you have a good idea how to solve this problem in an elegant way?

Comment: There's probably a way with `tikzmark` to add the space in the second  compilation run by measuring some stuff but I think there are better options available than TikZmark (see your updated or my answer).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, however, using `nicematrix`, you still get this problem. At least if you add the lines like I do in my updated approach.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative with TikZ-CD.

The `vmatrix` style doesn't produce the exact same matrix … but close enough?

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}
\tikzcdset{
  no arrow tips/.style={arrows=-},
  math matrix/.style={
    column sep=2*\the\arraycolsep, row sep=+0pt,
    cells={nodes={inner xsep=+0pt, outer sep=.1ex, inner ysep=.26\baselineskip}}},
  vmatrix/.style={math matrix, /tikz/every matrix/.append style={
    outer xsep=+-.14em, left delimiter=|, right delimiter=|}}}
\tikzcdset{
  --/.style={dash pattern=on1.5ptoff1.5pt},
  DU/.style={DU path={#1}, rotate=-45},
  UD/.style={DU path={#1}, rotate=45}}
\tikzset{
  DU path/.default=1, DU path/.style={rounded corners,
    to path={r-rl[rl distance=#1*.5cm](\tikztotarget)}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[vmatrix, no arrow tips]
  a_{11} \drar           & a_{12} \drar           & a_{13} \\
  a_{21} \drar \urar[--] & a_{22} \drar \urar[--] & a_{23} \\
  a_{31}       \urar[--] & a_{32}       \urar[--] & a_{33}
  \arrow[from=3-1, to=2-3, DU]
  \arrow[from=3-2, to=1-3, DU=2]
  \arrow[from=3-3, to=1-2, UD=2, --]
  \arrow[from=2-3, to=1-1, UD,   --]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[vmatrix, no arrow tips,
  DU/.style={DU path={#1}, rotate=-45, yslant=.3333},
  UD/.style={DU path={#1}, rotate= 45, yslant=-.3333}
] % only changes are the DU and UD paths
  a_{11} \drar           & a_{12} \drar           & a_{13} \\
  a_{21} \drar \urar[--] & a_{22} \drar \urar[--] & a_{23} \\
  a_{31}       \urar[--] & a_{32}       \urar[--] & a_{33}
  \arrow[from=3-1, to=2-3, DU]
  \arrow[from=3-2, to=1-3, DU=2]
  \arrow[from=3-3, to=1-2, UD=2, --]
  \arrow[from=2-3, to=1-1, UD,   --]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image][image]

Comment: The `inner ysep=.36\baselineskip` is bad but I don't know exactly how `array` and `tabular` constructs their rows …