# Displaying decimal divisions

Tags: nicematrix, tikz-calc

Here is a way to display decimal divisions. I have indicated the problem I am facing. I suspect that the use of some calculation is needed here.

[image]

I know that `xlop` exists, but for several reasons I am developing a `LuaTex` tool to display some human calculations

Here is the MWE used.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{10}{l}}
    1 & 2 & 3 &   & & \rlap{14}
    \\
      & 1 & 1 & 0 & & \rlap{8.7857142}
    \\
      &   & 1 & 2 & 0
    \\
      &   &   &   & 8 & 0
    \\
      &   &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0
    \\
      &   &   &   &   &   & 2 & 0
    \\
      &   &   &   &   &   &   & 6 & 0
    \\
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 4 & 0
    \\
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 & 2
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (1-|6) -- (3-|6) ;
        \draw (2-|6) -- (2-|7) ; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your tikz is probably better than mine but can't you put  an empty node or tikzmark or somesuch  `\rlap{8.7857142\HERE}` then use its coordinate to get the length of the rule?

Comment: That is a simple and good idea. I try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize your diagrams are not written by a human but here's a different solution anyway.

I'd go for a de-coupling of the content of the matrix (the single digits) and the part with the lines.

Here I'm setting up a matrix where every node in the second row gets the alias `dd@matrix-lastentry`. Of course, only the last one in the row actually holds this name. (→ No empty nodes, please.)

Then, after the matrix this node is used to place the result and the divisor.
Since I haven't used a `row sep` or a `column sep` the nodes are placed tightly adjacent to each other which I'm recreating here.

I'm using the fact that both nodes have the same height in the next step where I let TikZ create a pseudo-node around those nodes (very similar on how the `fit` library works) which I reference for the drawing of the two lines.
If the content of your cells is more complex this needs to be adjusted and fine-tuned but I don't think this is going to be necessary.

The `inner sep` for all nodes is set in the `tikzpicture` so that the two extra nodes have the same padding as the matrix nodes and blend in.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
  every DecimalDivision diagram/.style={
    inner sep=+.25em, % tighter nodes → no row sep or column sep
    M/.style={every DecimalDivision matrix/.append style={##1}},
    t/.style={DecimalDivision top={##1}},
    b/.style={DecimalDivision bottom={##1}}},
  every DecimalDivision matrix/.style={
    every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=+0pt},
    matrix of nodes,
    row 2/.append style={nodes={alias=dd@matrix-lastentry}}},
  DecimalDivision top/.initial=1,
  DecimalDivision bottom/.initial=1}
\newenvironment*{DecimalDivision}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every DecimalDivision diagram,#1]
  \matrix[every DecimalDivision matrix]\bgroup
}{%
  \\\egroup;
  \draw[local bounding box=dd@matrix] % a simple “fit”
   node[anchor=north west,
     xshift=width("0")+2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep})] (dd@matrix-bottom)
     at (dd@matrix-lastentry.north east) {
       \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/DecimalDivision bottom}}
   node[anchor=south west]
     at (dd@matrix-bottom.north west) {
     \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/DecimalDivision top}}
   (dd@matrix.north west)--(dd@matrix.south west)
   (dd@matrix.east)      --(dd@matrix.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{DecimalDivision}[t=14, b=8.7857142]
    1 & 2 & 3                             \\
      & 1 & 1 & 0                         \\
      &   & 1 & 2 & 0                     \\
      &   &   &   & 8 & 0                 \\
      &   &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0             \\
      &   &   &   &   &   & 2 & 0         \\
      &   &   &   &   &   &   & 6 & 0     \\
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 4 & 0 \\
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 & 2
\end{DecimalDivision}
\begin{DecimalDivision}[t=8, b=1.5]
    1 & 2     \\
      & 4 & 0 \\
      &   & 0
\end{DecimalDivision}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: The great thing about this solution is that I try to produce packages with manual tools complemented by automatic features. Christmas is coming early for me this year. :-) As usual, I will cite this post in my source code.

Comment: @projetmbc :D I have yet another remark for you: [I haven't found a good way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664296/use-tikz-or-anything-else-to-draw-the-demonstration-figure-for-the-3rd-order-mat/664311#comment1652095_664311) to imitate `array`s or `tabular`s with a TikZ `\matrix` perfectly. The horizontal spacing isn't the problem, that's just using `\arraycolsep` or `\tabcolsep` for the `inner xsep`s (or double that for `column sep`) but TeX builds rows very different than TikZ. Though, I'd call this hardly a real tabular anyway, so … happy holidays?

Comment: One last question. How can I decorate the diagram? I would like for example to draw one arrow from the last 12 to the first one, followed by a zero, in the first division to indicate the periodicity. What is the way to use the matrix coordinates in this case?

Comment: @projetmbc Since both `1` and `2` are two single nodes, you will need to `fit` a node around it (either with the `fit` library or with the `local bounding box` solution in this answer) which you can then use like any other node. Or – since all nodes are the same size – you might get away with a well-chosen anchor on one of the single nodes. Of course, we could add a smart key `repeating` that does these things automatically.

Comment: But what are the names of these nodes?

Comment: @projetmbc Give the matrix a name (either with `name=<name>` or the usual `(<name>)` and then you can reference the nodes with `<name>-<row>-<column>`. (Instead of giving the matrix a name we could use the uniqute name that TikZ gives automatically for it via `\tikzlastnode` in an `append after command` but there are no disadvantages for using our own name.) If you need some automatic way of finding out the first column with a node in a row I may have some ideas that are too long for a comment.

Comment: So simple. I do not need an automatic way. My idea here is also to have the possibility to use decorations for pedagogical purpose, and not only to stress the periodicity. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of David Carlisle, that is thinking graphically, and not about the text of the result, here is a solution that uses `tikzmark`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{10}{l}}
    1 & 2 & 3 &   & & \rlap{14}
    \\
      & 1 & 1 & 0 & & \rlap{8.7857142 \tikzmark{END}}
    \\
      &   & 1 & 2 & 0
    \\
      &   &   &   & 8 & 0
    \\
      &   &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0
    \\
      &   &   &   &   &   & 2 & 0
    \\
      &   &   &   &   &   &   & 6 & 0
    \\
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 4 & 0
    \\
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 & 2
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (1-|6) -- (3-|6) ;
        \draw (2-|6) -- (2-|{pic cs:END}) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{5}{l}}
    1 & 2 &   & & \rlap{8}
    \\
      & 4 & 0 & & \rlap{1.5 \tikzmark{END2}}
    \\
      &   & 0
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (1-|5) -- (3-|5) ;
        \draw (2-|5) -- (2-|{pic cs:END2}) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As a warning, both the drawn lines and the `\rlap`ped numbers don't update any bounding box and any content that comes after the diagram will protrude into it. This is of course only of concern when these are used inline (which they probably aren't) but it also affects centering and might not warn about an overfull hbox with very wide diagrams.

Comment: Thanks for this. I keep it as a warning for my future package.