# Array of numbers with arrows

Tags: arrows, arrays

In Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Walter Rudin utilizes the following array of numbers:

[image]

I want to recreate it in TeX but I don't even know how to start. Can someone help me?

EDITED:
I tried to edit some of the answers in post cited in Alenanno's comment. It kinda worked, but I couldn't make the arrows parallel.

My attempt:

```
$$
\begin{array}{*{6}{c}}
& \tikzmark{e1}x_{11}\tikzmark{s1} & x_{12}\tikzmark{s2} &  x_{13}\tikzmark{s3} & \cdots \\
\\
& \tikzmark{e2}x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23}\tikzmark{s4} & \cdots \\
\\
& \tikzmark{e3}x_{31} & \tikzmark{e4}x_{32} &   \tikzmark{e5}x_{33}\tikzmark{s5} & \cdots \\
& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{array}
$$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}
  \draw[<-] ($(s\i.north east)+(-0.1,0.1)$) -- ($(e\i.south west)+(0.1,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: 'Just' the array or also the diagonal lines?

Comment: Related (possible duplicates): [Drawing Multiple Diagonal Arrows in a Table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38169/4778), [Drawing Arrows in Tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37738/4778).

Comment: Please try the solutions inside of those linked questions. It shouldn't be hard to edit those. If you still have problems, you can edit your question showing what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Edited the post.
Christian, the array is easy to do. I couldn't figure out the diagonal lines.

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro: Yes, but please don't use `$$` -- that's outdated syntax. Use `\[....\]` instead if you need display math style

Comment: And please post a complete example we can compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to use the Ti*k*Z `matrix` library. The arrows may be added using a simple loop and the automatic names assigned by the `matrix of nodes` operation.

[image: parallel arrows]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes]
  {
    x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} & \dots \\
    x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24} & \dots \\
    x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} & x_{34} & \dots \\
    x_{41} & x_{42} & x_{43} & x_{44} & \dots \\
    \dots \\
  };
  \foreach \i in {1,...,4} \draw [->] (m-\i-1.south west) -- (m-1-\i.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (and TikZ to draw the arrows). The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` is similar to the environment `{tabular}` (as provided by `array`) but creates PGF/TikZ nodes under the cells, rows and columns. Then, it's possible to draw whatever rule you want with TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceMatrix}
  x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} & \cdots \\
  x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24} & \cdots \\
  x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} & x_{34} & \cdots \\
  x_{41} & x_{42} & x_{43} & x_{44} & \cdots \\
  \Hdotsfor{5} \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz  \foreach \i in {2,...,5} 
            { \draw [->,shorten > = 2pt] (\i-|1) -- (1-|\i) ; } ;
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]